# Passing variables from javaFX controller to other controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've just started programming a couple of months ago for school, and I'm currently making a luggage registration system in JavaFX. My first 3 screens is where you fill in needed information into textfields. After those 3 screens the next one has to feature a summary of everything that the user has filled in in the previous 3 screens. After watching numerous tutorials on how to pass on variables between controllers, i can't get it to work.

This is my initial controller

```
   @FXML
private void handleButtonAction1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, Exception {

    labelNumber = label_number.getText();
    flightNumber = flight_number.getText();
    destination = destination_.getText();

    if (nullOrEmpty(labelNumber) || nullOrEmpty(flightNumber) || nullOrEmpty(destination)) {

        warningLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        warningLabel.setText("Please fill in every field");

    } else {

        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        //Set the second screen fxml document on stage.
        SetStage setStage1 = new SetStage(stage, "FXML1Document.fxml");

        //Pass variables onto FXML3document.fxml
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXML3Document.fxml"));
        FXML3DocumentController FXML3DocumentController = loader.getController();
        FXML3DocumentController.SetTextLabelInfo(labelNumber, flightNumber, destination);
        MyJDBC myJDBC = new MyJDBC("fysdatabasefinal");

        String query = "INSERT INTO luggage(label_number,flight_number,destination) VALUES ('" + (labelNumber) + "','" + (flightNumber) + "','" + (destination) + "')";

        myJDBC.executeUpdateQuery(query);

        myJDBC.close();

    }

}
```

On pressing a button, it's supposed to take me to the next controller(FXML1Document.fxml). It's also supposed to pass the given variables to FXML3Document.fxml

This is FXML3DocumentController

```
public class FXML3DocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label first_name;
@FXML
private Label last_name;
@FXML
private Label email_address;
@FXML
private Label phone_number;
@FXML
private Label address_;
@FXML
private Label postal_code;
@FXML
private Label state_;
@FXML
private Label city_;
@FXML
private Label choice_country;
@FXML
private Label type_;
@FXML
private Label brand_;
@FXML
private Label color_;
@FXML
private Label label_number;
@FXML
private Label flight_number;
@FXML
private Label destination_;
@FXML
private Label special_char;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}
@FXML
public void SetTextClientInfo(String first_name, String last_name, String email_address, String phone_number, String address_,
        String postal_code, String state_, String city_, String choice_country) {

    this.first_name.setText(first_name);
    this.last_name.setText(last_name);
    this.email_address.setText(email_address);
    this.phone_number.setText(phone_number);
    this.address_.setText(address_);
    this.postal_code.setText(postal_code);
    this.state_.setText(state_);
    this.city_.setText(city_);
    this.choice_country.setText(choice_country);


}
@FXML
public void SetTextLabelInfo(String label_number, String flight_number, String destination_) {
    this.label_number.setText(label_number);
    this.flight_number.setText(flight_number);
    this.destination_.setText(destination_);

}
@FXML
public void SetTextLuggageInfo(String type_,
        String brand_, String special_char) {
    this.type_.setText(type_);
    this.brand_.setText(brand_);
    this.special_char.setText(special_char);

}
```

I've created 3 functions that i call in each of the 3 controllers, that get the textfield values and change the labels in the above controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: understanding the concept of MVC could be beneficial to your luggage program https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm

Comment: The controller isn't created if you don't load the FXML. And the controller is specific to the UI elements you load; since you're not displaying the UI from the FXML loaded, you want see the text in the labels (or the labels at all). I'm guessing your `SetStage` class actually loads and displays the contents of the FXML; if so, you need to get the controller from there.